# C Queue cleanup pointers

Tags: c, pointers, queue

Hello I'm writing simple based on LinkedList queue in C, and I had problems with releasing pointers.

I had a problem with deleting my queue. Function QueueDestroy should iterate whole queue and sequentionally remove first element and then next and next until end.

Removing first element is made by QueueDeleteFirst(struct * Queue) function that check if element first is the same that rear element

```
void QueueDeleteFirst(struct Queue * queue){ 
    if(queue->front == queue->rear){
        free(queue->front);
        // free(queue->rear); //This Give me "double free or corruption (fasttop)"
        //So I only set rear to null
        queue->rear = NULL;
     } else {
         queueNodeT * tmp = queue->front->next;
         free(queue->front);
         queue->front = tmp;
     }
}
```

My question is about correctness of this (QueueDeleteFirst) function because I'm learning C and need some guidelines.

I know that in C passing pointer into function pass it by value so I had local copy but in my case I don't need to pass

```
struct Queue ** queue
```

because all I need is to free first element but not whole struct Queue. So it is correct way to remove first element?

Next thing is QueueDestroy(struct Queue ** queue) here I need to use double pointer because I need free(queue) pointer and QueueDestroy(struct Queue * queue) will only free local pointer copy?

The whole my code below:

queue.h

```
typedef char queueElementT;

typedef struct queueNodeTag {
              queueElementT element;
              struct queueNodeTag *next;
            } queueNodeT;

struct Queue {
    queueNodeT *front, *rear;
                } ;

void QueueDestroy(struct Queue * queue);
void QueueEnter(struct Queue * queue, queueElementT element);
void QueueDeleteFirst(struct Queue ** queue);
int QueueIsEmpty(struct Queue * queue);
struct Queue * QueueCreate(void);
```

queue.c

```
#include "queue.h"

static queueNodeT *NewNode(queueElementT element);

struct Queue * QueueCreate(void){
  struct Queue * queue;
  queue = (struct Queue *)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
  if (queue == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient memory for new queue.\n");
    exit(1);  
  }
  queue->front = queue->rear = NULL;
  return queue;
}

void QueueDestroy(struct Queue ** queue){
  while (!QueueIsEmpty(*queue))
      QueueDeleteFirst(*queue);
  (*queue)->front = (*queue)->rear = NULL;
  free(*queue);
  *queue = NULL;
}

void QueueEnter(struct Queue * queue, queueElementT element) {
  queueNodeT *newNodeP;
  newNodeP = NewNode(element);

  if (queue->front == NULL) {  /* Queue is empty */
    queue->front = queue->rear = newNodeP;
  } else {
    queue->rear->next = newNodeP;
    queue->rear = newNodeP;
  }
}

static queueNodeT *NewNode(queueElementT element){
  queueNodeT *newNodeP;
  newNodeP = (queueNodeT *)malloc(sizeof(queueNodeT));
  if (newNodeP == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient memory for new node.\n");
    exit(1); 
  }

  newNodeP->element = element;
  newNodeP->next = NULL;

  return newNodeP;
}

int QueueIsEmpty(struct Queue * queue){
    return queue->front == NULL || queue->rear == NULL;
}

void QueueDeleteFirst(struct Queue * queue){
    if(queue->front == queue->rear){
        free(queue->front);
        queue->rear = NULL;
     } else {
         queueNodeT * tmp = queue->front->next;
         free(queue->front);
         queue->front = tmp;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of parameter passing is quite correct, but You have a logical error in your `QueueDeleteFirst`. When freeing the front you implicitly `free` the `rear` element also, and both pointers should be set to `NULL` (`queue->front = queue->rear = NULL`). This would solve your cleanup problem.

I cannot see how `QueueDestroy` will compile as `queue->front` does not exists?

Comment: Sorry this is mistake in QueueDestroy should be written  (*queue)->front = (*queue)->rear = NULL;

Comment: it is now ok? (after editing (*queue)->front = (*queue)->rear = NULL )

Comment: Seems compilable to me :)